# IOS Background service accessible from other applications

Tags: ios, objective-c, service, background

Is it possible to create an IOS Background Service ? Can it also be accessible from other applications?

Comment: if its for the job maybe start with some research? It's not anything you couldnt find on the internet easily, dont expect people to do the job for you... also precise how would you like to acces the service, what data you want to pass wht is this bacground service supposed to do, also there are limitations for background services, are you aware of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without jailbraking the phone. And most certainly not for distributing over the AppStore.

You could create an application (with UI) that would be accessible to other applications via custom URL schemes (you could even set URL callbacks with the same mechanisms).

But it would be up to the user if they would decide to run or kill this app. It would not be a typical 'background task'.

Comment: thank you ,so an application can communicate with a background application via URL ?Please have you some Links can help me because i don't really understand :(

Comment: i would not really call it a background application. when you call it via URL scheme it will "jump" to foreground. you should experiment a bit to see if you could make this mechanism fit your needs: [Inter-App Communication](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html)

Comment: Take a look at [App Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/app-bundles/). I believe you still need to upload apps one-by-one, but then you can create boundle of them.

Comment: if i have two applications communicate with custom URL , how can I upload the two applications on AppSore  together ?

Comment: thank you rokjarc , therefore no solution for an application during his instalation obliged to install another application !?

Comment: Theoretically you can check (frome one application) using `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:...]` if your other application is installed - and advise the user to install it (and possibly provide a direct link). It is not an elegant solution though. You might also have some problems passing the App Store approval with such 'configuration'. You didn't give any info on what kind of service you want to provide to your users so it's hard to give better advice.

Comment: The service (my second application) will access to a webService and send push notification to the first application,  So my first application cannot be useful without the second appli  
Thanks for your help